# PHP regexp how to get value from parentheses?

Tags: php

Input:

> Gujarat (24)

Expected Output:

> 24

How can I get value from parentheses?

Comment: Use `/\(\K\d+(?=\))/` https://regex101.com/r/8Wsfuv/1

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
$state = 'GUJRAT (24)';
preg_match('/\(([\d]+)\)/', $state, $res);
$code = $res[1];
echo $code;
```